# Send notification to users when product is created in OctoberCMS?

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I have a plugin that creates a product and I want to send a notification email to all users when a new product has been created, how do i approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Events`](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/events)

`Fire` an event when the product is created and `Listen` to the respective event to send notification mail to the users.

```
Event::fire('product.create', [$product]);
```

Register the listener within the boot method of the plugin

```
public function boot()
{
    Event::listen('product.create', function ($product) {

       // Send Mail to subscribed users

    });
}
```

Comment: I've added the Event::listen event to myPlugin\Products\Plugin.php, where does the Event::fire go?

Comment: In the controller where the product is created, or check for any events in the plugin documentation where it emits events for product creation, so that you could use that event name instead

Comment: It's a custom plugin so i'll have to create my own event, it's logic is is in it's component folder so I'll have to create this there, will an onCreate or onAddItem function class name work ?

Comment: You should fire the event in the component where you would be creating the product

Comment: If its a plugin you developed yourself, there is no point in using Events. Why dont you just send the email when the product is added?
You can call the function that sends the email in you Product model `afterCreate()` function. Or is the question about how to send the email?